# From JSON data to CSV encoding

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv

I'm reading json data and converting it into a .csv file in python3.

I called the "utf-8" encoding like:
`csv = open(download_dir, "w", encoding='utf-8')`
When writing I coded something like this:
`csv.write(str(message.content_excerpt[:30].encode("utf-8")) + ';')`

I have two problems:

1. The enconding is outputing on EXCEL with messed chars
2. I want to get rid of blank lines due the original post formating.

Example 1 shows the actual cenario, Example 2 shows what I want to get.

**Example 1 (actual)**
[image: Example 1 (actual)]
**Example 2 (pretended)**
[image: Example 2 (pretended)]

Thank you!

Comment: What does your original JSON data look like?

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue you have, I need the source code for the JSON.

As for the second issue - 
The simplest way to ignore blank lines that I know is

```
for row in csv.reader(file_handler):
    if row:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Sounds like the OP is reading from JSON and producing CSV - this shows CSV->CSV

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas module from python, which will provide you both the methods `read_json` and `to_csv` with encoding parameter. also you can get rid of blank lines with pandas `dropna` method. see below example.

```
    import pandas as pd

    df=pd.read_json("test.json", encoding="utf-8")
    print(df)
    df.dropna()     #drop all rows that have any NaN values
    df.dropna(how='all')     #drop only if ALL columns are NaN
    df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```